# Issue with DateTime.ParseExact method: always throws exception even with correct format

Tags: c#, exception, datetime

I have searched the forum for solutions like this, however I did not find one that actually matches my particular issue.

This might be in need of a more experienced eye in order to find the problem, so I appreciate all help!

Problem: I am trying to parse a string with a date to a DateTime variable. However, even if the string date format is exactly the same, it still throws an exception.

I would like to know why, and how I can solve it. I really can't see what is wrong there!

```
try
{
   string value = "Sep-17-2012 03:04:07 am";

   string format = "M-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";

   DateTime temp = DateTime.ParseExact(value, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

Thanks in advance,

Mad

Comment: You can also use `TryParseExact` instead of the try catch block. it probably fails faster than try catch.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Silvermind. Is it also true that if the TryParseExact fails it will return null?

The try catch could be more useful since I'd like to know what was the error that caused the exception. It kind of really depends on what the user needs the code to do!

Comment: Actually the error thrown is very generic and is just a `FormatException` with a message `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` So it won't get more specific than that. `TryParse` returns `true` if it parses and `false` if not, where it uses the `out` keyword to pass the value to a reference. See [`DateTime Methods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/497a406b.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your format should be MMM not M http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

```
string format = "MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
```

> M   -  display one-digit month number
>
> MMM -  display a three letter month

Comment: @LuisVale Please do not forget. If this answer solved your problem to select the checkmark on it. Thanks

Comment: Damnit, I don't know how I missed it. I kind of got confused because I'm using the datetimepicker object (as found in here: http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html) and there it shows the format M as the name of the month. I forgot to check the actual meaning in DateTime object for "M". Thanks AMR! I'll have to figure out a way to parse it, since it means different things in both objects. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Your format string is not correct:

```
string value = "Sep-17-2012 03:04:07 am";

string format = "MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";

DateTime temp = DateTime.ParseExact(value, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Ref:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you need MMM for month.

```
try
{
string value = "Sep-17-2012 03:04:07 am";

string format = "MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";

DateTime temp = DateTime.ParseExact(value, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
} 
 catch(Exception e){}
```